# Can't get value of POST via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

I'm searching for about 4 hours and I still don't understand, why this code doesn't work.

I am using Codeigniter framework, csrf is off, xss filtering is off.

My js:

```
var url_to_ajax = base_url + "ajaxcalls/newcomment";
$.ajax({
        url: url_to_ajax,
        type: "POST",
        data: {parent_id: "a"},
        success: function ( data ) {
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

and in controller:

```
public function newcomment() {

        $parent_id = $this->input->post('parent_id');

        echo "please print it: ".$parent_id;
        print_r($_POST);
}
```

`$parent_id` is empty and `$_POST` is an empty array.. In the alert I see  "please print it: Array ( )" and that's all.

Does someone know why I can't get that "a" in alert from controller?

Comment: check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, see if your script is actually handling a post. something may have caused a redirect and converted your post into a get.

Comment: You are right, echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; prints GET, but why? However, GET is empty array too...

Comment: Sake of argument, have you tried jQuerie's `$.post(...)` instead of just `ajax`? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @FrankV yes, i tried, same result

Comment: _“However, GET is empty array too... ”_ – well, POST parameters don’t magically become GET parameters when the page is redirected. As to _why_ the method is changed to GET (assuming it was POST to begin with, which you should verify in your browser’s debug tools), that’s for you to find out – check your routing, and whatever else might affect incoming POST requests.

Comment: just installed new copy of CI, welcome view changed to your ajax request, controller - your code - everything works fine. so conclusion is  - some CI settings are different and/or wrong so try to compare CI config files with defaults from the original package

Comment: what is name of your controller. if this "ajaxcalls" is in default controller then you must add this function in routes.

Comment: @KimAlexander this is what i didn't want to do, but it resolved my problem ;) thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine for me. May be there is a mistake in URL. Try this code and see if any error message comes.

```
var url_to_ajax = base_url + "ajaxcalls/newcomment";
$.ajax({
        url: url_to_ajax,
        type: "POST",
        data: {parent_id: "a"},
        success: function ( data ) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are not using url rewrite, use "index.php" with base_url. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url + "index.php/ajaxcalls/newcomment",
    type: "POST",
    data: {parent_id: "a"},
    success: function ( data ) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using url rewrite

Comment: plz check my updated answer. use 'url' directly inside the $.ajax